# Full screen always enabled when opening app in OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, safari, fullscreen

How can I set my Macbook Air to always open new apps in full screen mode?

Some apps already do it (Mail for example), but others are always opening as a small window, especially Safari when I close (cmd+W) all the tabs.

Is there a setting, a terminal command line, or anything to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an option called resume I think - check out this post. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4140495?tstart=0.  To quote the answer, you can do

> System Preferences > General > Uncheck 'Close windows when quitting an
>   application'

Not exactly what you want, but it's a possible alternative maybe?